# When can a polynomial be written as a sum of squares of other polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

The *Princeton Companion* briefly mentions the general question was 'interesting' and 'difficult' without providing any reference.  Can someone shed light on why this is so?

Comment: Single or multi-variable?  Coefficients in...?

Comment: Both.  Why is the multivariate case particularly interesting?

Comment: The single-variable case is sort of trivial (at least over real). A real polynomial in single-variable can be written as a sum of two squares of real polynomials iff it is non-negative for all its argument. This isn't the case for polynomials over multi-variables.

Answer (score 0):

For polynomials in a single variable the "Pythagorean triples" of polynomials are determined by more or less the same condition as Pythagorean triples of integers. So, if $p$, $q$, and $r$ are polynomials, then $p^2 + q^2 = r^2$ if and only if there exist polynomials $u$ and $v$ such that $p = u^2 - v^2$, $q = 2uv$, $r = u^2 + v^2$

See
K. K. Kubota, 
"Pythagorean triples in unique factorization domains", 
The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 79, No. 5 (May, 1972), pp. 503-505.

This is interesting (to me) because it tells me how I can parameterize circles with rational functions. It's also the foundation of a class of curves called "Pythagorean hodograph" curves, which are useful because their offsets are easy to construct. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262150/bezier-unit-tangent/270841#270841), for example, or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302076/offseting-a-bezier-curve/302101#302101).